# Not receiving messages in the reply queue that sent to RabbitMQ using amqplib and processed by NestJS

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, nestjs

So I'm using NestJS (v8) with the RabbitMQ transport (`Transport.RMQ`) to listen for messages

My NestJS code look something like this:

```
// main.ts

const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(AppModule, {
  transport: Transport.RMQ,
  options: {
    urls: ['amqp://localhost:5672'],
    queue: 'my-queue',
    replyQueue: 'my-reply-queue'
  },
});
```

```
// my.controller.ts

import { Controller } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MessagePattern } from '@nestjs/microservices';

@Controller()
export class MyController {
  @MessagePattern('something')
  do(data: {source: string}): {source: string} {
    console.log(data);

    data.source += ' | MyController';

    return data;
  }
}
```

And in Node.JS application, I use [`amqplib`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqplib) to send to the NestJS application and receive the response

this is the code of the Node.JS application:

```js
const queueName = 'my-queue';
const replyQueueName = 'my-reply-queue';

const amqplib = require('amqplib');

async function run() {
  const conn = await amqplib.connect('amqp://localhost:5672');
  const channel = await conn.createChannel();

  await channel.assertQueue(queueName);
  await channel.assertQueue(replyQueueName);

  // Consumer: Listen to messages from the reply queue
  await channel.consume(replyQueueName, (msg) => console.log(msg.content.toString()));

  // Publisher: Send message to the queue
  channel.sendToQueue(
    queueName,
    Buffer.from(
      JSON.stringify({
        pattern: 'something',
        data: { source: 'node-application' },
      })
    ),
    { replyTo: replyQueueName }
  ); 
}

run()
```

When I run the node and the Nest.JS applications, the Nest.JS gets the message from the Node.JS publisher but the Node.JS consumer is never called with the reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix was to add an `id` key in the data that the Node.JS application sends:

```js
// ...

// Publisher: Send message to the queue
channel.sendToQueue(
  queueName,
  Buffer.from(
    JSON.stringify({
      // Add the `id` key here so the Node.js consumer will get the message in the reply queue
      id: '',
      
      pattern: 'something',
      data: { source: 'node-application' },
    })
  ),
  { replyTo: replyQueueName }
); 

// ...
```

---

### Detailed explanation (in Nest.JS source code)

This is because in the [`handleMessage` function](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/026c1bd61c561a3ad24da425d6bca27d47567bfd/packages/microservices/server/server-rmq.ts#L124-L165) in `server-rmq.ts` file there is a check if `id` property of the message is `undefined`

```
// https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/026c1bd61c561a3ad24da425d6bca27d47567bfd/packages/microservices/server/server-rmq.ts#L139-L141

 public async handleMessage(
    message: Record<string, any>,
    channel: any,
  ): Promise<void> {
    // ...

    if (isUndefined((packet as IncomingRequest).id)) {
      return this.handleEvent(pattern, packet, rmqContext);
    }

    // ...
  }
```

And there is no logic of sending messages to the reply queue in the [`handleEvent` function](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/026c1bd61c561a3ad24da425d6bca27d47567bfd/packages/microservices/server/server.ts#L104), just handling the event

Comment: Save my time, thnx!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code in client service:

```
  const result = this.active_pairs_client.send(pattern, data).pipe(
  timeout(DEFAULT_RMQ_TIMEOUT), // Set the timeout in milliseconds
  catchError((error) => {
    if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
      // Handle timeout error
      console.error("Request timed out");
    }
    throw error;
  })
);
```